# Posting a string on my wall from iOS App?

Tags: facebook, ios5, xcode4.2

I'm new to Facebook development. Can someone guide me 
on how can I post on my wall from an iOS app?

Comment: Did you Google for this? I think the answer can be found there.

Comment: yeah... but didn't find a clear answer... can you provide my any link..I'm using xcode 4.2

Comment: I've added the resources as answer. That should help you.

Comment: Thanx bro... the examples worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by integrating the Facebook SDK in your app.

Get started here: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/

Here's a specific example: 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/publish-to-feed-ios-sdk/